# Why doesn't delay() work?

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
<div id="Test">test</div>

$('#Test').delay(5000).html('').hide('slow');
```

I need the DIV to close after 5 seconds, but it closes immediately.

What do I need to change so that it closes after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will delay only methods which uses queue to get executed like animation(), fadeIn() etc

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

Use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#Test').removeClass("test1").removeClass("test2").html('').hide('slow');
}, 5000)
```

or use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to delay the execution of later code

```
$('#Test').delay(5000).queue(function(){
    $(this).html('').hide('slow');
})
```

Comment: but why not work delay?

Comment: @TeoLine delay by default is for FX effects.(its not for change display stuff). best approach is queue.

Comment: .delay() adds to the queue, .html doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the last two method calls in reverse...

```
<div id="Test">test</div>
$('#Test').delay(5000).hide('slow', function(){
    $(this).html('');//only when done remove the content
});
```

However as @Royi Namir noted... the delay() is really meant for use within an animation sequence... so you might need a "fake" animation first (basically a no-op) and then the delay.

```
<div id="Test">test</div>
$('#Test').css({'opacity':0.95}).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide('slow', function(){
    $(this).html('');//only when done remove the content
});
```

This is a bit of a hack... force a fadeIn animation... delay... then hide slowly... and clear out the contents.  If you truly want to remove the contents first you can but it would make the hide() animation sort of redundant.

Comment: its not the same sequence as the OP wants.

Comment: Agreed its not the same order - but I'm not sure if that was intentional or not.  As noted in the linked "potential duplicate" question using the .queue() is actually a better approach.